# why would an aircraft use 3 red flashing lights?

Tags: navigation

i saw an aircraft taking off from a supposedly disused airfield with 3 flashing red lights. i live close to Woodford Aerodrome and saw it taking off from there with 3 flashing red lights! i was stood outside having a smoke watching the stars on a lovely clear and very cold night at half 12 and there it was climbing above the roof tops. so i'm curious.

Comment: Welcome to av.se!  Unfortunately, "3 red flashing lights" is so little to go on, I suspect that your question is likely to not be well received. A red light on the left wingtip (albeit normally steady) plus a red anti-collision beacon top + bottom is a very, very standard setup for vast numbers of aircraft, so getting a meaningful answer to the question as stated is unlikely. If you can see the aircraft in daylight & provide a better description, or ideally a photo, you're much more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: I live near the old Woodford aerodrome and have just seen something very similar. An aircraft with only red navigation lights. It was moving NE to SW (right to left for my view) at a constant but not particularly fast speed. I'm a lifelong aircraft fanatic with 4 years in the air cadets & I'm a qualified skydive. Never seen anything without the standard navigation lights & wondered if anyone had any further thoughts.

Comment: Is it possible it was something like a drone or other remotely controlled vehicle? The smaller the vehicle, the lower the lighting standards...

Answer (score 2):

Each plane has 2 Anti-Collision Lights Top and bottom.
A plane also has navigation lights where left is red and right is green these face forward. Navigtion lights are always and don't flash it could look like it if somthing small came in front like birds.
[image: Anti-Collision Lights]
[image: navigation lights[2]]

Comment: The Lockheed L-1011 Tristar had two anti-collision light on top and two on the bottom. I believe this was because the Tristar was designed from the start for autoland in lower visibility minimas than other aircraft at the time and the designers figured in bad weather it would be good to have more lights?